# D3 Circle-Packing Clear Labeling Solution

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

Is there a way in d3's packing layout to set the radius of a child node manually, with a size relative to the parent radius, and then have the other children set their radius' based on the remaining space and using the existing "size by number of children"?

What I would like to do is:
1. for each node add a node to the children array with the same name as the parent
2. set the radius of this extra child to have a significant enough radius to contain text and ensure no overlap from its neighbors
3. set fill and stroke to none on this extra node
4. set the click interaction via css to none on this extra node
5. use only these extra nodes to display "their" names (aka their parent's names)

The result would be a packed circle with a specially designated space for its labels. This does not work without a manual setting of the extra child node's radius because it's size is automatically determined based on the number of children. (adding children unfilled/unstroked nodes to compensate is extremely inefficient. The second hack for the first hack just wouldn't be worth it I don't think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is the solution I am using for now, and builds upon the solution Ganesh provided.

Summary of Ganesh's solution:

- Introduce a function that runs over your data and injects an extra node into each node's child array, except for when it examines a leaf node.

Remaining Issues for my use of Ganesh's solution:

- Not all parent nodes had values, so they did not have labels
- There was no indication for how node values were calculated, they were already provided in the json data
- The extra nodes created for labels were too small, as it's neighbors always grew to accomodate it's children.

Solution and key findings:

- Value is determined based on the sum total of children of a node
- Leaf nodes in my example had a value of 100
- The root node had a value of roughly 31,700, which is roughly accurate since it has a total of 316 children (direct and transitive), counting itself
- Therefore, I updated my data so that each node also includes the size of it's subtree
- The final version of my value function, based on Ganesh's solution is provided below:

  ```
          var pack = d3.layout.pack()
          .value(function(d){ 
              if(d.isExtra){ //the property added to injected label nodes
                  d.value = d.parent.treeSize*100 //treeSize = size of subTree
                  return d.value;
              }
              else{
                  d.value = d.treeSize*100;
                  return d.value;
              }
          })
          .size([width, height -100 ])
  ```

It is important to note here that while I am introducing a new node with a value equal to it's parent node times 100, this does not mean that it takes 100 times the space of the circle. This is because a parent's value is ultimately the sum of it's children's values, which means that any node that had a child, will see an increase in total value. Multiplying the treeSize for label nodes by significantly higher numbers only provides a logarithmic increase in corresponding circle size, while introducing a larger and larger gap between leaf node size (100) and the rest of the circles.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this helps you.The circles with red background with with class 'extra' is the extra circles with parent's name.

[jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/vekebu/edit?css,js,console,output)

```js
var root = {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
 ]
};
var addExtraNode = function(item, percentSize){
  var percentSizeOfNode = percentSize || 60; //if not given it will occupy 60 percent of the space
  if(!item.children){
    return;
  }
  var totalChildSize = 0;
  item.children.forEach(function(citm, index){
    totalChildSize = totalChildSize + citm.size;
  })
  
  var nodeSize = (percentSizeOfNode / 50) * totalChildSize;
  var name = 'NAME: '+item.name;
  item.children.push({
    'name': name,
    'size': nodeSize,
    'isextra':true
  })
  
  item.children.forEach(function(citm, index){
    if(citm.children){
      addExtraNode(citm, percentSize);
    }
  })
};

addExtraNode(root, 55);

var diameter = 500,
    format = d3.format(",d");

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(2,2)");


 
var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes)
 .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      
      if(d.isextra){
        return 'extra';
      }
      return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name + (d.children ? "" : ": " + format(d.size)); });

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }).append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".3em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
```

```css
circle {
  fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);
  fill-opacity: .25;
  stroke: rgb(31, 119, 180);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.leaf circle {
  fill: #ff7f0e;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.extra circle{
  fill:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ganesh you are a genius Good Sir! I wish I could by you a beer :)

Comment: I have a question still though before I would be able to apply your answer to my situation, and that is related to the pack.value function / your size parameters. I am still very new with d3, so can you help me to 1) better understand what the value function does? 2) Understand how you arrived at the size values you used. I know that the documentation for d3 says value is what determines the circles' size, but I don't see exactly what the correlation is. I try adjusting some or all of the sizes in your answer, but it does not resize based on any hypothesis I had about how it works.

Comment: Also, what does this line of code do?  `node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name + (d.children ? "" : ": " + format(d.size)); });`

Comment: That code is for showing tooltip over the nodes. Try mouseovering on the circle you will show Name:size. It checks if node has children it shows blank and its a leaf node it shows you the size infront of name. So only leaf nodes   show the size with name.

Comment: if you find my function call addExtraNode(root, 55); here 55 is the percentage you want if you change this number the size of the extra node will change. .value function of d3 pack layout takes function which returns specific column of the dataobject associated with the element. in our case its 'size'. This function is evaluated by d3 to determine the diameter of the nodes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the values for size in your original root object. You have sizes ranging in the several thousands. Why are the numbers in that range, my original thought was that these sizes were related to areas of the circles maybe?

Comment: the sizes in my example are in thousands but they are scaled for the available area. The size() function takes length and width which defines the limit of visualisation. This is scaled per each item. And your understanding is correct the value() are accessors which are related to areas of the circles.  This tutorial may help, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-dataviz2/